# Multiprocesing 500 events 10 by 10?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Good evening all,

I would like to run a something like 500 process at the same time and decided to write a pool managing the work. However it is very heavy and the memory does not look like it will handle it. 
Any recommendation to open/use a pool that will execute the processes 10 by 10 or 50 by 50 ? 
Thanks

Here is the way I am processing right now.

```
def get_data_mp(args):
    settings = args

    procs = len(settings.ticker_list)
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(procs)
    tickers = pool.map(get_file_mp, [(settings,i) for i in range(procs)])
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Usually the number of procs is around 500. The function get_file_mp is quite heavy therefore when everything is in memory, the computer suffers a lot. That is why I d like to have a method to exectue those processes 10 by 10 or 50 by 50 as I noted that the computer was able to handle this load of work.

Comment: Python has a multi-processing pool that manages everything for you. Check https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html. It's unclear to me how you tried to run the 500 processes. Please elaborate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create two threads, one is your event queue thread and the other is an event dispatch thread.

- The event queue thread is where your 500 processes would send there event to. Once it get's an event it sleeps.
- The event queue thread will wait till a threshold of jobs arrive or a time from last event dispatch has occurred. Your threshold would be 10 or 50 or whatever you want.
- On reaching this threshold or time it would batch 10 or 50 event and pass them to the job dispatch thread and go to sleep again
- Your event dispatch thread would iterate over the events and call the handler for each, and then go to sleep again.

That's if you really want to batch process events, I would personally prefer not to batch them though and try to optimise their execution in "real time".

Comment: Thanks.Sounds smart. 
Why would you not recommend to batch them ? And how would you try to optimise ? I really looked for the little loops that could be optimise but the memory doesnt like i all. I must say tho that I am still quite new with programming so any idea or recommendations would be a great thing for me :)

Comment: You're welcome. The reason for not recommending batching is because it is more complex, adds more code, introduces delays in event processing and bunches up your memory using and processing and smoothing it out